# How to call other activity after timer count down end

Tags: android, timer

this is my timer class , i whant to call other activity when the timer is enb. 
       enter code here

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TimerCountDown extends CountDownTimer {





    private TextView timerTextView;






    public TimerCountDown(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);





    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        getTimerTextView().setText((String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "S")));




    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
       getTimerTextView().setText("0s");


       //need to start activity 

    }





    public TextView getTimerTextView() {
        return timerTextView;
    }

    public void setTimerTextView(TextView timerTextView) {
        this.timerTextView = timerTextView;
    }



}
```

and this the activity i what to displayed

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by eli on 5/1/2016.
 */
public class Playagin extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_again);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make private member Context in your TimerCountDown class. When you create your timer pass Context (in most cases your current Activity via "this") in your timer. In onFinish method start Playagin activity using context.

Your timer class should looks like this.

```
public class TimerCountDown extends CountDownTimer {

    private TextView timerTextView;
    private Context context;

    public TimerCountDown(long startTime, long interval, Context context) {
        super(startTime, interval);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        getTimerTextView().setText((String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "S")));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
       getTimerTextView().setText("0s");

       context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Playagin.class));
    }

    public TextView getTimerTextView() {
        return timerTextView;
    }

    public void setTimerTextView(TextView timerTextView) {
        this.timerTextView = timerTextView;
    }
}
```